# How do I declare CSS styles for children of the same class with just one declaration?

Tags: css

I have this declaration:

```
.myClass td, .myClass tr, .myClass table, .myClass img {margin:0, padding:0;}
```

I do not want to repeat ".myClass", I would rather write it as something like below:

```
.myClass (td, tr, table, img) {margin:0, padding:0;}
```

I know the above is not correct, so how would I achieve this in correct syntax?

Comment: With CSS you can't; with [tag:less] or [tag:sass] you can.

Comment: Thank you, but less or sass are preprocessors that will yield the same result on the final page/css file, correct? I was thinking if there is a way to have this as the end result, but I assume I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

.myClass > * { margin:0;padding:0; }

Comment: That won't affect `.myClass tr td` only immediate children of `.myClass` but you should also add a disclaimer that it will affect all elements inside that one without the `>`.

Comment: You can make it `.myClass *` and that will work.

Comment: Thank you, but this is **not** what I want. I do not want **all** children to get that style but just the ones I mention above (tr,td, etc.). 

So, the question still holds, does CSS has any rule to allow for that in a shorter syntax? (than just repeating the .myClass for each child element?)